# Ajv Default Values for Typescript Interfaces

Tags: typescript, jsonschema, ajv

I am trying out the `useDefaults` feature of Ajv to validate input data and populate it with defaults.  Validating a property-less object should produce an object with all default values applied.

This is my code:

```js
import Ajv, { JSONSchemaType } from 'ajv';

const data = {};

interface DataModel {
    product: {
        version: string,
    },
}

const dataSchema:JSONSchemaType<DataModel> = {
    type: 'object',
    properties: {
        product: {
            type: 'object',
            default: {}, // Comment out or use { version: '2.3.4' }
            properties: {
                version: {
                    type: 'string',
                    default: '1.2.3',
                }
            },
            required: ['version'],
            additionalProperties: false,
        }
    },
    required: ['product'],
    additionalProperties: false,
};

const ajv = new Ajv({useDefaults: true});
const validate = ajv.compile(dataSchema);
if (!validate(data)) {
    throw validate.errors;
}
console.log(data);
```

The console output I am expecting is `{ product: { version: '1.2.3' } }` but I get a compiler error instead:

```
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
zzzschema.ts:11:7 - error TS2322: Type '{ type: "object"; properties: { product: { type: "object"; default: {}; properties: { version: { type: "string"; default: string; }; }; required: "version"[]; additionalProperties: false; }; }; required: "product"[]; additionalProperties: false; }' is not assignable to type 'JSONSchemaType<DataModel>'.
  The types of 'properties.product' are incompatible between these types.
    Type '{ type: "object"; default: {}; properties: { version: { type: "string"; default: string; }; }; required: "version"[]; additionalProperties: false; }' is not assignable to type '{ $ref: string; } | (UncheckedJSONSchemaType<{ version: string; }, false> & { nullable?: false | undefined; const?: { version: string; } | undefined; enum?: readonly { ...; }[] | undefined; default?: { ...; } | undefined; })'.
      Types of property 'default' are incompatible.
        Property 'version' is missing in type '{}' but required in type '{ version: string; }'.

11 const dataSchema:JSONSchemaType<DataModel> = {
         ~~~~~~~~~~

  zzzschema.ts:7:3
    7   version: string,
        ~~~~~~~
    'version' is declared here.
```

I can "fix" that in several ways: I can remove `default: {}` from the `product` definition - comment out line 16 - but then the default is not applied as intended, and the data does not validate:

```json
[
  {
    instancePath: '',
    schemaPath: '#/required',
    keyword: 'required',
    params: { missingProperty: 'product' },
    message: "must have required property 'product'"
  }
]
```

The other possibility is to not use the Ajv feature [Utility types for schemas](https://ajv.js.org/guide/typescript.html#utility-types-for-schemas) and to change the schema type from `JSONSchemaType<DataModel>` to `any` but that is unsatisfying.

A third possibility would be to use `{ version: '2.3.4' }` as the default for `product`. However, that is ugly because my schema is in reality modularized and I want to define the defaults where the schema is defined and not one level above it.

In case it matters: I'm using Ajv 8.12.0 with TypeScript 5.1.6.